# Angular ui-leaflet Map ,satellite hybrid option going under the map?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

so i want the button that let me choose satellite and hybrid to stay open and seen, but as soon as the map load, the map layer go over the the button. i can see the button is still there when i suddenly move or zoom out where the map render the button shows up for a second also on the developer tools i can see. i played with z index and some css tricks , nothing seem to work out. Below the red line is the div containing the button .[image]

using
"angular": "1.5.9",
"leaflet": "^1.0.3",
"leaflet-omnivore": "^0.3.4",
"leaflet.markercluster": "^1.0.4",
"ui-leaflet": "^1.0.3"

```js
constructor(leafletData, siMapUtils, $rootScope, $log, siMapRam, $mdSidenav) {
    "ngInject";

    this.name     = 'map';
    this.loading  = false;
    this.map      = {};
    this.showNotification = false;
    this.mapId = 'map-dashboard';

    this.leafletData = leafletData;
    this.siMapUtils = siMapUtils;
    this.siMapRam   = siMapRam;
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope
    this.$log       = $log;
    this.$mdSidenav = $mdSidenav;

    this.defaulLayerName = 'Hybrid',
    this.defaultLayerUrl = 'http:***********.png',
    this.layersType      = 'xyz',
    this.xyzLayerName    = 'Satellite',
    this.xyzLayerUrl     = 'http://*********';

  }

  $onInit = () => {
    this.initMap();

    this.map = {
      options:{},
      layers:{ 
        baselayers: {
            defaultLayer: { name: this.defaulLayerName, url: this.defaultLayerUrl, type: this.layersType,layerOptions:{maxZoom:21 , maxNativeZoom: 18} },
            xyz: { name: this.xyzLayerName, url: this.xyzLayerUrl, type: this.layersType, layerOptions:{maxZoom: 21, maxNativeZoom: 17} }
        },
          overlays: {}
      },
      center:{ lat: this.loadData.map.latitude, lng: this.loadData.map.longitude, zoom: this.loadData.map.zoomLevel | 1}
    }
  }

  toggleEvents = () => {
    this.$mdSidenav('right').toggle();
  }

  initMap = () => {
    var self = this;

    //save data in ram service to pull elsewhere (like in search)
    this.siMapRam.saveAssets(this.loadData.assets);
    
    let markersGroup = this.siMapUtils.buildMarkerLayer(this.loadData.assets);

    this.leafletData.getMap(this.mapId).then(function(map) {
        //coordinates = document.getElementById('coordinates');
        
        /*if(self.previousLayer != null){
            map.removeLayer(self.previousLayer);
        }*/
        map.options.minZoom = 3; //change to constant
        map.options.maxZoom = 21; //change to constant
        
        //mapDet = map;//?
        //build marker layer
        map.addLayer(markersGroup); 

        //_PL = markersGroup;
        
        /*map.on('baselayerchange', function (event) {
              _rs.$broadcast('baselayerchange', { layerName: event.name });
        });*/
    }, (err) => { 
      self.$log.error(`error fetching map during initialization`)
    }).
    then(function(){
        self.$log.info('done loading markers ...');
        //getLegend();
    }, (err) => { 
      self.$log.error(`error initializing map: ${err.message}`);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.angular-leaflet-map{
  z-index:0;
}


.leaflet-top, .leaflet-bottom {
    z-index: 1000 !important;
    position: relative;
}

.map-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.marker {
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 1;
  max-height: 48px;
  max-width: 48px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.marker-dot {
  background-color: black;
  height: 15px;
  max-width: 15px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  left: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -85px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.icon-badge {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  right: -21px;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 25px;
  max-width: 13px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.button-icon {
  margin: auto 3px auto 0;
}

.auto-overflow {
  overflow: auto;
}

.bottom-right-filter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.bottom-left-layer {
  position: absolute;
  color: $dark-font;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.filter-button-background {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.top-left-button-margin {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.search-controller-layout {
  position: absolute;
}

.search-autocomplete {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 0;
}


.search-filter{
  background-color: white;
  margin-left:10px;

  & > md-autocomplete {
    & > md-autocomplete-wrap {
      box-shadow: none;
    }
  }
}

#dashboard-ts{
  & > md-select {
    & > md-select-value{
      color: $dark-font;
    }
  }
}


.autocomplete-asset-name {
  font-size: x-large;
  color: black;
}

.map-top-right-ctrl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.status-legend {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}



.leaflet-top{
  z-index: 5;
}

.leaflet-control-attribution {
  display: none;
}


.leaflet-control-zoom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  margin-left:10px !important;
}

.map-wrapper {
  &#dashboard {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
  &#asset-detail {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  &#asset-location {
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
}


.leaflet-top, .leaflet-bottom {
  z-index: 10 !important;
}





.legend {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #555;
  width:100%;

  i{
    color: #777;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}

.leaflet-draw-toolbar a {
  background-image: url('/content/png/spritesheet.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  background-image: url('/content/png/layers.png');
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  bottom: 25px;
}
.leaflet-retina .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  background-image: url('/content/png/layers-2x.png');
  background-size: 26px 26px;
  bottom: 25px;
}


.leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
  float: right;
  top: 40vh;
  font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #555;
}

.leaflet-draw-toolbar{
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.cursorCardContent{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 350px;

}

.cursorCardStyle{
  bottom: 35px;
  right: 15px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999
}

.cursorCardTitles{
  margin: 6px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.anchorsStyle{
  height: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 6px ;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: inherit;
}

.leaflet-bottom-card {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}




/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
  /* Styles */

  .dg-modal{
    width:650px !important;
  }
}


@media only screen 
  and (max-width:350px)
  and (min-width:320px){
  .search-autocomplete{
    width:246px;
  }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width:350px)
and (max-width:360px){
  .search-autocomplete{
    width:287px;
  }
}

.zoomLevel{
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.updateLocationMap{
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.selectdemoSelectHeader .demo-header-searchbox {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 48px;
  width: 222px;
  padding: 0; 
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.selectdemoSelectHeader .demo-select-header {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 222px; 
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#tenantSelector{
  display: flex;
  margin: 8px 3px 9px 3px !important;
}

.alert-icon {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.leaflet-top, .leaflet-bottom {
  z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

removing this solved the issue, this z index was covering the icon zindex.